# How do I add an integer value with javascript (jquery) to a value that's returning a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, casting

I have a simple html block like:

```
<span id="replies">8</span>
```

Using jquery I'm trying to add a 1 to the value (8).

```
var currentValue = $("#replies").text();
var newValue = currentValue + 1;
$("replies").text(newValue);
```

What's happening is it is appearing like:

81

then

811

not 9, which would be the correct answer.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

parseInt() will force it to be type integer, or will be NaN (not a number) if it cannot perform the conversion.

```
var currentValue = parseInt($("#replies").text(),10);
```

The second paramter (radix) makes sure it is parsed as a decimal number.

Comment: Be careful of parseInt(), it recognizes "010" as 9 (values leading with a zero are parsed as octal).

Comment: Bleh, "010" parses as 8 (not 8)

Comment: @Jacob Relkin : Since this was useful, I just gave him another +1. If you know of a better answer, it's a pity you didn't share it.

Comment: I've come here with google about 3 times already. wish I could vote up thrice :p

Comment: Why the `10` as the 2nd parameter? Doesn't `parseInt` by default parses in base 10?

Comment: It does, unless it detects a leading zero, then it becomes octal. A simple glitch when accepting user input.

Comment: It works fine as long as you specify the radix by using the second parameter:  `parseInt("010", 10)` returns ten.

Comment: If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal) [is used].  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 29):

Parse int is the tool you should use here, but like any tool it should be used correctly. When using parseInt you should always use the radix parameter to ensure the correct base is used

```
var currentValue = parseInt($("#replies").text(),10);
```

Answer (score 28):

The integer is being converted into a string rather than vice-versa. You want:

```
var newValue = parseInt(currentValue) + 1
```

Answer (score 12):

parseInt didn't work for me in IE. So I simply used + on the variable you want as an integer.

```
var currentValue = $("#replies").text();
var newValue = +currentValue + 1;
$("replies").text(newValue);
```

Answer (score 5):

In regards to the octal misinterpretation of .js - I just used this...

```
parseInt(parseFloat(nv))
```

and after testing with leading zeros, came back everytime with the correct representation.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

to increment by one you can do something like

```
  var newValue = currentValue ++;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should like this:

```
<span id="replies">8</span>

var currentValue = $("#replies").text();
var newValue = parseInt(parseFloat(currentValue)) + 1;
$("replies").text(newValue);
```

[Hacks N Tricks](http://rajeevcse04.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 2):

Simply, add a plus sign before the text value

```js
var newValue = +currentValue + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var month = new Date().getMonth();
var newmon = month + 1;
$('#month').html((newmon < 10 ? '0' : '') + newmon );
```

I simply fixed your month issue, getMonth array start from 0 to 11.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the variable by 1 to force JavaScript to convert the variable to a number for you and then add it to your other value.  This works because multiplication isn't overloaded as addition is.   Some may say that this is less clear than parseInt, but it is a way to do it and it hasn't been mentioned yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can use parseInt() method to convert string to integer in javascript

You just change the code like this

```
$("replies").text(parseInt($("replies").text(),10) + 1);
```

Comment: How is this different from above posted answer ( which are posted around 10 year ago ) ?