# Why does this concatenate instead of adding up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Very very basic question but I've got the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="nspcc" value="0" onkeyup="doTotal();" />
<input type="text" id="barnados" value="0" onkeyup="doTotal();" />
<input type="text" id="savethechildren" value="0" onkeyup="doTotal();" />
<input type="text" id="childresnsociety" value="0" onkeyup="doTotal();" />
<input type="text" id="childreninneed" value="0" onkeyup="doTotal();" />
<input type="text" id="total" disabled="disabled"  />
```

And the following jQuery:

```
function doTotal() {
  var one,two,three,four,five,total;
  one = $('#nspcc').val();
  two = $('#barnados').val();
  three = $('#savethechildren').val();
  four = $('#childresnsociety').val();
  five = $('#childreninneed').val();
  total = one+two+three+four+five;
  $('#total').val(total);
}

doTotal();
```

I'm probably doing something daft but why does `total` concatenate instead of adding the values? Do I need to use `parseInt` or something?

Comment: yes, because the result of `.val()` is always of type string. Use `parseInt(one, 10)` etc.

Comment: .val() returns a string.
parse away.

Comment: Same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460172/how-do-i-add-an-integer-value-with-javascript-jquery-to-a-value-thats-returni

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I need to use parseInt or something?

Yes. The `.val()` method returns a string, so you need to make sure you're operating on numbers instead (since the `+` operator is overloaded to perform both addition and concatenation depending on context):

```
one = parseInt($('#nspcc').val(), 10);
//etc...
```

Don't forget the second argument (the radix) to `parseInt`!

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to use parseInt or something?

Exactly. `val()` will return *strings*, which will get concatenated and not added up.

Do note that when using `parseInt` you should supply the radix parameter (second one) for the correct base - 10 for decimal, otherwise it will *assume* octal.

```
one = parseInt( $('#nspcc').val() , 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes. You'll need to parseInt() your .val() values as they're string interpretations of the values, so they'll simply concatenate.